# Direct column and row excel

Tags: python, excel

In my Excel sheet I have columns with names for example in first row has got name Smith, it gives me one specific information about product, in next column I have the same name Smith and it gives me other specific information about product.
I would like to write a program which outputs a new Excel file where data is united and name Smith is in one row instead of two or more with all specific information I need from other columns.

I really do not know how to start with this.
What I can make is print whole specific row or column:

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    print(row[2].value)

for column in sheet.columns:
    print(column[2].value)
```

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "C:\\My files\\Staff\\Project\\ProjektExcelPython\\test_files\\"
book = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, "PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx"))
#spreadsheet_file = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, "PlikExcelDoKonwersji.xlsx"), engine='openpyxl', header = 1)

sheet = book['sheet1']

for row in sheet.rows:
    print(row[2].value)

for column in sheet.columns:
    print(column[2].value)
```

There are many excel packages which one will be the most efficient to start creating such program?

[image: Data with output]

My idea is to create a loop which iterate every row and get specific information and add to the columns in other Excel.
If name is the same add to the same row in other Excel.

I also think about making list of dictionary with data using JSON, I saw sth like this around.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Python script, you should use pivot table, in pivot table, put product name column in pivot column field and qty column in value field and remaing column will goes to row pivot field. for formatting of data Design tab>report layout>(tabluar form, repeat) and (Subtotal>do not show sub total) –

row data for example are as follow

[image]

final summary

[image]

second full details images

[image]

Comment: Man that's really nice and also Can I my new kind of information, new column like "Additional Info"

Comment: Off course, only you have to convert your row data into table format  after that whenever you add new information in row data then it will automatically reflect in pivot table after refresh the pivot table